# Noob javascript 1 line explication

Tags: javascript

What does the following line do?

```
(flag)?flag=false:flag=true;
```

In this piece of code:

```
  var flag = true;
    function resize() {
        if(flag) {
            document.getElementById("centerimg").style.width = "150%";
            document.getElementById("centerimg").style.height = "150%";
            document.getElementById("center").style.left = 120+"px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("centerimg").style.width = "100%";
            document.getElementById("centerimg").style.height = "100%";
            document.getElementById("center").style.left = 190.5+"px";
        }
        (flag)?flag=false:flag=true;
    }
```

Comment: The same thing as `flag = !flag;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is using what is called the ternary operator. It follows the same logic as an if-else statement, just a more condensed version. Standard format is `condition ? true block : false block`

The `(flag)` is checking a boolean condition - in this case it is seeing if `flag` evaluates to `true`. Between the ? and : is the action to perform if the boolean condition is true - setting `flag` to false in this case. The section after the : is what happens if the condition was false - setting `flag` to true.

So if we write this longhand it ends up as

```
if (flag) {
    flag = false;
} else {
    flag = true
}
```

Which can be further shortened into `flag = !flag` (`flag` is equal to the opposite of `flag`)

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as if you wrote:

```
if(flag){
    flag = false;
}else{
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you explane in words the logic?

Comment: If there is a flag(or the flag is truthy) set the flag to false else (the flag is falsey), set it to true.
What is truthy and falsey: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 1):

Ask if the flag is true, if flag is true, then change it to false, if the flag is false, change it to true.

Answer (score 0):

a?a=true:a = false is [**CONDITIONAL OPERATOR**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

It is used to set the value of `a` to `b` or `c` depending on conditions.

In your case , it does the same thing as `flag = !flag`

Answer (score 0):

It's using the JavaScript conditional (or ternary) operator to flip the flag.  It's a shortcut  for the if statement.  See [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

If flag is true, set flag to false.  Otherwise, set flag to true.